# Creating a reverse lookup table from measured values

Tags: c++, arrays, math, lookup

I'm recording two voltages from an encoder (of known speed) during calibration. Creating this (voltage over angle), then I need to measure the voltages and get the corresponding angle.

[image: Two voltages over angle]

I would like to find values in between recorded points too for more precision, some sort of arccos lookup table, but I'm stuck and can't make an efficient way to do that.

Do I have to research my value in the array by comparing a lot of them? That would be very slow, right?

I have tried using an arccos function but that wouldn't compensate for mechanical irregularities I guess.
Also I already calculated the averages and amplitudes of the waves.

Edit: As asked, the goal is to measure the position of a motor for FOC.
The setup is as follows:

[image]

This is what I get with the atan2 function:

```
x = 2*(hallA.read() - moyenneA)/(maxA-minA);
y = 2*(hallB.read() - moyenneB)/(maxB-minB);
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have sin and cos curves so you could use atan2-function to calculate the angle. What mechanical irregularities are you talking about?

Comment: I suggest clarifying your answer making it clear Arccos is referring to arc cosine function. It took me a bit to figure that out.

Comment: Yes, it's a sin and cos, the hall sensors are pi/2 apart.
Maybe the magnetic field of the rotor isn't straight, or the magnet isn't perfectly centered @Keijo

Comment: I suppose you could do simple polynomial interpolation between the recorded sin and cos values to increase the sampling rate. Based on those values you can estimate the irregularity parameters and apply the corresponding correction to measurements. I am not completely sure what is the result you are actually looking for.

Comment: Okay, from your last comment. I think you're trying to calculate the angle of the rotor of an electric motor. Likely to feed it into a PID (proportional–integral–derivative) controller to control motor speed. If that's the case I'd suggest adding that goal to your question. Just so people know the goal of the calculation.

Comment: It is said in the first sentence that the speed is known and something is being calibrated. Maybe the magnet eccentricity? Yes, the goal would be nice to know as well as the physical model of the system.

Comment: @JeffSpencer We have a sleuth! I will do that

Comment: @Keijo that's part of the issue yes! Also because of the amplifier, resistor tolerances etc, I cannot get the sines to be exactly between 0 and 3.3V, so i need to measure the offset and amplitude before anything

Comment: Ok, so you first have to come up with a model of your system where the offset and amplitudes are parameters. Then use a parameter estimation algorithm to fit the measured data into the model and find out the parameters. Maybe Matlab / Octave would help you more than C++.

Comment: I already can calculate the offset and amplitude, the thing is we have an array that stores a voltage for a given angle, but the goal is to an array that stores an angle for two given voltages.
Sorry if I can't describe the issue correctly

Comment: Well if you know the offset and amplitudes, then apply them to correct the measured voltages to get clean sin and cos samples. Then we are back to where we began: use atan2 to convert sin and cos samples to angles.

Comment: the sinwaves might be distorted also in angular axis not just in amplitude... for example the magnetic field might not be exactly circular, the phases might not be  exactly 90 deg etc, so acos/asin/atan2 approaches might be very inaccurate ... the easiest is to use "binary" search + interpolation for the angle finding 2 points in table where the voltages is below on one side and above on the other side then just linearly interpolate the intersection where the voltage would be exactly the value then just compute the angle To use binary search you have to separate monotonic parts of the tables

Comment: can you post your measured values also in text form (ideally C++ source code of the tables array)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you can't add any more information to your data than you already have. Except by sampling more often. That said, you could use linear interpolation to estimate what the voltage would be between any two measured points. Look up linear interpolation for the details but to summarize if you have a point C in time between points A and B that is 25% of the way between A and B. Then you calculate the voltage that is weighted the same. So Voltage C = Voltage A + 25%(Voltage A - Voltage B).

As for calculating the angle, that's not my area of expertise. But I think I'd calculate the linear interpolated value 1/2 sample time behind the point I'm interested in and the interpolated value 1/2 sample time ahead of the point I'm interested in and calculate the angle of the slope. But, I am not a signal processing expert. There's been many books written on that subject. There are other interpolation functions available, reading about signal process interpolation on the Internet will probably get you tons of more info.

If you have a concern about mechanical or electrical noise in your data, then I would recommend using a smoothing algorithm. I know fast Fourier transforms are very popular. But I'm sure there are many other options. There must be filtering libraries and algorithms on the Internet. But as I say, this isn't my area of expertise. Maybe my response will trigger someone else to answer with more expertise. One method of eliminating high frequency noise is simply to sample less often.

Comment: The linear interpolation is what I meant 

But how would I structure that? do I make a table such as this?
angle[ ] = { angle at 1mV, angle at 2mV, angle at 3mV }

Answer (score 1):

If interpolation is what you want, you will need a *reconstruction filter* to reconstruct the measured signal from a set of samples, or at least to get an (optimal) interpolation between sampled values to arrive at a dataset that suits your needs.

The most basic way is a linear interpolation; add, for instance, one value between two measurements that is the average of those two measurements. This is a simple algorithm, and you could just generate a new, larger dataset from the old one, or interpolate on the fly.

Most oscilloscopes use a sin(x)/x reconstruction filter which provides a more accurate reconstruction of the sampled input signal than linear interpolation does.

If you want to get rid of irregularities, you could use a moving average filter, or a (more complex) FIR filter, but this will make things slower when you are processing "live".

If you want to know more (and probably more than I know), you could try asking his question on EE; they have all the theory needed for what I suspect you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Well as other s mentioned already your data contains noise, and distortion in amplitude. However its more than likely your data also contains temporal distortion (angle parameter of sinwave is non linear nor in exact/constant phase shift) That would make use of `atan,acos,asin` very inaccurate and problematic.

I would:

1. **FIR filter the data**

   so use sliding average centered around value so the output will not phase shift. This is `O(n)` and one only once. Do not forget to use temp array...
2. **detect monotonic intervals**

   simply detect the intervals where your signals are only decreasing or only increasing... This is also `O(n)` and done one only once.
3. **use binary search**

   simply go through all intervals and if your measured voltages are inside their range (first and last value of the interval) use binary search on the interval. The selection of interval is `O(1)` as number of intervals is always `4` or `5` depending on the starting phases.

   binary search itself is `O(log(n))`

**Here a small C++/VCL example:**

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMain *Main;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LUT data
const int n=1317;
double atan2_u0[n];         // u0 [V] red
double atan2_u1[n];         // u1 [V] blue
//  ix = ang*183/50         // index -> [deg]
// ang = ix*50/183          // [deg] -> index

// monotonic intervals
const int m=10;             // max interval count
int atan2_n=0;              // intervals count
int atan2_ix[m];            // interval start index
int atan2_s0[m];            // direction of atan2_u0
int atan2_s1[m];            // direction of atan2_u1
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double LUT_atan2(double _u0,double _u1)
    {
    int i,i0,i1,m;
    double u,u0,u1,U0,U1,s0,s1;
    // process interals
    for (i=0;i<atan2_n;i++)
        {
        i0=atan2_ix[i];
        i1=atan2_ix[i+1]-1;
        // test BBOX
        u0=atan2_u0[i0]; U0=atan2_u0[i1]; s0=atan2_s0[i];
        u1=atan2_u1[i0]; U1=atan2_u1[i1]; s1=atan2_s1[i];
        if (s0<0.0){ u=u0; u0=U0; U0=u; }
        if (s1<0.0){ u=u1; u1=U1; U1=u; }
        if ((_u0<u0)||(_u0>U0)) continue;
        if ((_u1<u1)||(_u1>U1)) continue;
        // binary search
        for (m=1;m<=(i1-i0);m<<=1); m>>=1; if (!m) m=1; // m = exp2(log2(i1-i0))
        for (;m;m>>=1)
            {
            i0+=m;
            if (i0>i1){ i0-=m; continue; }
            u0=atan2_u0[i0];
            u1=atan2_u1[i0];
            if (((_u0-u0)*s0<0.0)||((_u1-u1)*s1<0.0)) i0-=m;
            }
        return double(i0)*50.0/183.0;
        }
    return 0.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LUT_atan2_init()       // filter u0,u1 and compute intervals
    {
    int i,j,k,r;
    double u0,u1,du0,du1,U0,U1,tmp0[n],tmp1[n];
    // centered sliding avg, window is <-r,+r>
    r=25; du0=1.0/double(r+r+1);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)   // all samples
        {
        u0=0.0; u1=0.0;
        for (j=i-r;j<=i+r;j++)
            {
            k=j;
            if (k< 0) k+=n;
            if (k>=n) k-=n;
            u0+=atan2_u0[k];
            u1+=atan2_u1[k];
            }
        tmp0[i]=u0*du0;
        tmp1[i]=u1*du0;
        }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        atan2_u0[i]=tmp0[i];
        atan2_u1[i]=tmp1[i];
        }
    // find monotonic intervals
    atan2_n=0; atan2_ix[0]=0;
    u0=atan2_u0[0]; U0=atan2_u0[1]; atan2_s0[0]=0.0;
    u1=atan2_u1[0]; U1=atan2_u1[1]; atan2_s1[0]=0.0;
    for (i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
        // actual delta du0,du1
        u0=U0; U0=atan2_u0[i]; du0=U0-u0; if (du0<0.0) du0=-1.0; else if (du0>0.0) du0=+1.0;
        u1=U1; U1=atan2_u1[i]; du1=U1-u1; if (du1<0.0) du1=-1.0; else if (du1>0.0) du1=+1.0;
        if (fabs(atan2_s0[atan2_n])<1e-3) atan2_s0[atan2_n]=du0;
        if (fabs(atan2_s1[atan2_n])<1e-3) atan2_s1[atan2_n]=du1;
        // if sign changed add new interval
        if ((du0*atan2_s0[atan2_n]<-0.1)||(du1*atan2_s1[atan2_n]<-0.1))
            {
            if (atan2_n>=m-1) break;
            atan2_n++;
            atan2_ix[atan2_n]=i;
            atan2_s0[atan2_n]=du0;
            atan2_s1[atan2_n]=du1;
            }
        }
    // add end of table as end of intervals
    atan2_n++;
    atan2_ix[atan2_n]=n;
    atan2_s0[atan2_n]=0.0;
    atan2_s1[atan2_n]=0.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void data_generate() // extract mesurede values from image
    {
    int x,y,x0=44,y0=478,dx=227-x0,dy=y0-424,r,g,b,i;
    double u0,u1,du=1.0/double(dy);
    BYTE *c; DWORD *q;
    // convert bmp -> pnt[]
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->LoadFromFile("in.bmp");
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    for (x=x0;x<bmp->Width;x++)
        {
        u0=u1=-1.0;
        for (y=0;y<=y0;y++)
            {
            q=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
            c=(BYTE*)(q+x);
            b=c[0]; g=c[1]; r=c[2]; i=r+g+b;
            if ((r>200)&&(i<500)){ u0=y0-y; u0*=du; break; }    // [V]
            }
        for (y=0;y<=y0;y++)
            {
            q=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
            c=(BYTE*)(q+x);
            b=c[0]; g=c[1]; r=c[2]; i=r+g+b;
            if ((b>200)&&(i<500)){ u1=y0-y; u1*=du; break; }    // [V]
            }
        if (u0<-0.5) u0=u1;
        if (u1<-0.5) u1=u0;
        i=x-x0;
        atan2_u0[i]=u0+1.0;
        atan2_u1[i]=u1+1.0;
        }
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    if (!_redraw) return;

    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    int i;
    double x,y,dy=ys/10.0,r=5.0;
    // LUT
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clRed;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        x=(i*xs)/n;
        y=ys-(atan2_u0[i]*dy);
        if (!i) bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        else    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        x=(i*xs)/n;
        y=ys-(atan2_u1[i]*dy);
        if (!i) bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        else    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    // intervals
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clDkGray;
    for (i=0;i<=atan2_n;i++)
        {
        x=(atan2_ix[i]*xs)/n;
        bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,0);
        bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,ys);
        }


    // atan2
    double u0=8.0,u1=1.7,a;
    a=LUT_atan2(u0,u1);     // [V,V] -> [deg]
    x=(183.0*a*xs)/(50.0*n);    // [deg] -> [pixel]

    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clWhite;
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,0);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,ys);

    y=ys-(u0*dy);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clWhite;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clRed;
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);

    y=ys-(u1*dy);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clWhite;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);

    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    _redraw=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
    {
    data_generate();
    LUT_atan2_init();
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    pyx=NULL;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;  xs2=xs>>1;
    ys=ClientHeight; ys2=ys>>1;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    if (pyx) delete[] pyx;
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(int*) bmp->ScanLine[y];
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMain::tim_redrawTimer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I extracted the input data from image of yours and converted to `[V]` and `[deg]`. You can ignore the VCL rendering and window stuff. The only important thing here are these functions:

```
void LUT_atan2_init();
double LUT_atan2(double _u0,double _u1);
```

the first precomputes all the stuff needed (call just once) and the second returns angle in `[deg]` for voltages `u0,u1`.

This might however have slight accuracy problems if your `u0,u1` are near interval edge where one voltage is in one interval and the other in the next which might happen if noise is added. In such case you can do bianry search of `u0` and `u1` separately remebering the 2 locations for both and then chech the 4 combinations which one is the correct one. After that just use mid position between the found two indexes. For this you woul dhave the intervals separate too (but it would be just 2 or 3 per signal).

Also you can add **"sub pixel" precision** by adding linear interpolation after the binary search (I was too lazy for that so its not in my example)

Here preview:

[image: preview]

Red,Blue curves are your `u0,u1` signals, the gray lines are the found interval edges, dots are tested (measured) voltages and white is the found angle

Comment: First: Thank you very much!
Programming really isn't my area of expertise but I try to understand

Let's say I have an array containing recorded voltages for each thousandth of turn
double voltage[1000][2] = {   {0.0, 1.0} ,  { 0.01, 0.99 }, etc } 

then could I make a reverse array?

Comment: @antoineserry its not really a reverse array its still the same array, binary search just find the index in your array of measurement coresponding to 2 input voltages (in `O(log(n)` iterations which for 1000 measurements / 4 intervals is ~8 iterations....)